# Error in building hector_navigation

Tags: navigation, catkin, costmap, hector, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day to all.

I have encounter a few errors while building hector_navigation package.

https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_navigation/tree/catkin

I'm using catkin workspace. During catkin_make, I encountered these errors:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package costmap_2d.

  Set costmap_2d_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file
  for costmap_2d.  The file will have one of the following names:

    costmap_2dConfig.cmake
    costmap_2d-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_planner/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package nav_core.

  Set nav_core_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  nav_core.  The file will have one of the following names:

    nav_coreConfig.cmake
    nav_core-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_planner/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_exploration_node'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node)
CMake Error at /home/gordon/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_exploration_planner/cmake/hector_exploration_plannerConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findcostmap_2d.cmake or a configuration file for
  package costmap_2d.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findcostmap_2d.cmake or set costmap_2d_DIR
  to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for costmap_2d.  The
  file will have one of the following names:

    costmap_2dConfig.cmake
    costmap_2d-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /home/gordon/catkin_ws/devel/share/hector_exploration_planner/cmake/hector_exploration_plannerConfig.cmake:165 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findnav_core.cmake or a configuration file for
  package nav_core.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findnav_core.cmake or set nav_core_DIR to
  the directory containing a CMake configuration file for nav_core.  The file
  will have one of the following names:

    nav_coreConfig.cmake
    nav_core-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package)
  hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- +++ processing catkin package: 'hector_costmap'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(hector_navigation/hector_costmap)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;genlisp;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package pcl_conversions.

  Set pcl_conversions_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for pcl_conversions.  The file will have one of the following names:

    pcl_conversionsConfig.cmake
    pcl_conversions-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_navigation/hector_costmap/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Anybody knows how to correct these? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211688/error-in-building-hector_navigation/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you made sure to *first install all required dependencies*? Run a:

```
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

You might run into issues here as well, as you're running Groovy, which has long been EOL-ed (meaning that it might be that some pkgs that `hector_navigation` depends on are not available).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-19**:
OK! I installed the dependencies after building this:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/tree/groovy-devel-catkinized (Got costmap_2D and nav_core)

and installed:

$ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-pcl-conversions

The errors have been solved! Thanks!